# Where to put Flyway migrations in a Vaadin project (Java Servlet web app)?

Tags: maven, vaadin, vaadin7, flyway

Where does one put their [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org) migration files in a [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7 project created with the [multi-module Maven archetype](https://vaadin.com/maven#archetypes)?

I will activate the migrations through the Java API in Flyway (not the command-line).

Might the solution for Vaadin work in any [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Servlet) based web app project running in a [web container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_container) such as [Tomcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Tomcat) or [Jetty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jetty_(web_server))?

Comment: Do you mean the SQL files, or the java files?

Comment: @AndréSchild I suppose just the SQL files. Aren't the Java files just classes compiled as part of my Java web app?

Comment: Similar: [*Where to put data or config files loaded by my Java code when web app launches in a Vaadin 14 web app driven by Maven*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59996594/642706)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

As of 2018-06, the [Vaadin 8 archetype](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/getting-started/getting-started-archetypes.html) named `vaadin-archetype-application-multimodule` no longer provides an existing folders for `Web Pages`, `META-INF`, and `WEB-INF` as seen below in the *Previously* section. The `WEB-INF` and `classes` folders are created dynamically at build-time.

Look to your `foobar-ui` module’s folder. Locate the `src` > `main` > `resources` folder hierarchy. Add the nested folders `db` & `migration` following Flyway conventions.

[image: screen shot showing nested folders "db" and "migration" added to the "ui" module’s “src > main > resources” folder hierarchy.]

If we explode the resulting WAR file, we see that during the build process a `WEB-INF` folder was created, with a nested `classes` folder, where we find our `db` > `migration` folder containing our first added SQL script file.

[image: screenshot of file browser showing the exploded WAR file’ contents that includes a folder hierarchy of <code>WEB-INF</code> > <code>classes</code> > <code>db</code> > <code>migration</code> containing our added SQL script file]

## Previously

Prior versions of the multi-module Maven archetype provided by Vaadin Ltd. used a different arrangement than that seen above.

### Default folder nested in `WEB-INF`

Flyway by default will find your .sql migration files if located in this exact folder path:

> `/WEB-INF/classes/db/migration/`

[image]

In your project, in the `-ui` module, locate the `WEB-INF` folder. The [Java Servlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_servlet) spec defines this special folder as a place to store class files, .jar files, and other resources that should be made available to your servlets but always shield from outside, never available as a public part of the web app.

That `WEB-INF` folder will contain `classes` & `lib` folder. You may not yet see these two folders in your [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment)’s project view. These two special folders are created during the compiling and build process. The first houses individual .class files for your web app, while `lib` houses .jar files. Again, all this is defined by the Servlet spec.

**The Trick:** Manually create the `classes` folder in your IDE if not shown. What you place inside will be automatically merged with the other content destined for the `classes` folder when created during the compiling/build process.

Flyway by default looks on the classpath for a hierarchy named exactly `/db/migration/`. So create folders by these names inside that `classes` folder you added to `WEB-INF`. Now when Flyway looks on the [classpath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath_(Java)) at runtime, Flyway will look in `/WEB-INF/classes` and find `/db/migration/`.

So in your IDE:

1. Create a folder named `classes` in your project’s `WEB-INF`.
2. Create a nested folder named `db`.
3. Create a nested folder named `migration`.
4. Place your .sql files within that `migration` folder.

Run your Flyway migration. Here is example code using the [H2 Database](http://www.H2Database.com/) called in the `contextInitialized` method of my class implementing `[ServletContextListener][3]`.

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway ();
flyway.setDataSource ( "jdbc:h2:~/test" , "scott" , "tiger" );
flyway.migrate ();
```

### Caveat

Take this Answer with a grain of salt as I am new to Flyway. But this is working for me using [Flyway](http://www.flywaydb.org/) 4, [Vaadin](http://www.Vaadin.com/) 7.6.4, Java 1.8 Update 77, [NetBeans](http://www.NetBeans.org/) 8.1, [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) 8.0.27, Mac OS X El Capitan.