# Where to put data or config files loaded by my Java code when web app launches in a Vaadin 14 web app driven by Maven

Tags: servlets, directory, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In a Vaadin 14 web app project created by the "Plain Java Servlet" flavor of the [Vaadin Starter page](https://vaadin.com/start/latest), there are numerous folders automatically created by the Maven POM file process.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ "Project" pane showing folders nested within project]

Where is the place to put a data file or configuration file that I will load and parse when my web app launches? Under what folder do I put my files? Should I create further nested folders? And by what file path name do I find and load such a text (XML, JSON, CSV, etc.) file?

Comment: Similar: [*Where should I place my Vaadin 10+ static files?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57553973/642706)

Comment: Similar: [*Where to put Flyway migrations in a Vaadin project (Java Servlet web app)?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36634299/642706)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Location of file

You put them in `src/main/resources` as it is the convention also outside of a Vaadin application.

Vaadin adds several other resource roots for things that later end up in places in the jar, that are conventient for vaadin to find (e.g. under `META-INF/resources/...`).

`resources` still ends up in the root of the jar or get properly "classpathed" by the build-tools and is safe to load non-classes via the classloader in your application.

## Opening file

You can open your text file from there by calling [`Class::getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), returning an [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html). Note the leading slash character.

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream( "/myfile.txt" ) ;
```