# eClipse: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils

Tags: java, eclipse, classnotfoundexception, tomcat9, http-status-code-500

I made a folder in my eClipse root as `jars` and in sub folders of `jars` I placed the relevant jars.
I also added the classpath in `Java Build Path` by `Add External Jars`
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

`commons-dbutils-1.7.jar` is the jar that displaying

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.dbutils.DbUtils
```

eClipse is not displaying any code error but eClipse `Tomcat-9` on runtime displaying this and code is not running by showing the following:

```
HTTP Status 500 ? Internal Server Error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet execution threw an exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/dbutils/DbUtils

user.taxonomy.categories.DAO.selectAll(DAO.java:107)
    user.taxonomy.categories.view.HTML.selectAll(HTML.java:29)
    user.taxonomy.categories.SelectAll.doGet(SelectAll.java:64)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Please let me know where I am making mistake?

Best Regards
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaarw.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When deploying a project to a Tomcat server, the *"Build path"* of the project is irrelevant. What counts is the *"Deployment assembly"* of the project.

Check if all relevant libraries (especially `commons-dbutils*.jar`) are listed there.

Answer (score 1):

Your JARs should be in WEB-INF/lib so that Tomcat loads them automatically.

See

[What's the correct procedure to add JARs into WEB-INF/lib directory in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19803451/whats-the-correct-procedure-to-add-jars-into-web-inf-lib-directory-in-intellij)

For related info